# Adding a new Connector to GSA

Tags: google-search-appliance

I have GSA setup with one connector manager, and want to install new connector manually to an existing connector manager. Do I just need to add the new connector code to existing connector manager and re-start the server ?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to drop your connector jar into the proper libs folder. A restart is required.

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear what you are asking.  Each Connector Manager has the capability of creating connector instances.  If you want to create a new Connector Instance then you just create that from the Connectors page in the GSA.

If you want to create a completely separate Connector Manager instance then you need to have a separately running Connector Manager (using its own Tomcat and having its own port #).  You can then manually create the link to it in the GSA.

If you are adding an instance, there is no need to restart the Connector Manager.  You cannot add another Connector Manager to an existing one.

Comment: Thanks Terry, I need to add a new custom connector to an existing connector manager.